# Horizontal scroll on list

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I got a time line using list .It will be showing times between 00:00 to 24:00.I need to scroll to the left and right of the timeline without showing the scrollbar.

```
<div id="timeTableMask">
    <div id="timeTableInner">

        <ul id="timeText">
            <li class="t0000"><span class="hour">0:00</span></li>
            <li class="t0015">&nbsp;</li>
                    |
            <li class="t2345">&nbsp;</li>
            <li class="t2400"><span class="hour">24:00</span></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how the timeline looks like :

[image]

Comment: do a google [search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=horizontal+timeline&oq=horizontal) for `horizontal timeline` and if you got make a working snippet, so someone can help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow..What have you tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a summary of what you tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#timeTableMask {
 overflow: hidden;
  width:80px;
  border:solid 1px pink;
}
#timeTableInner {
 margin-bottom: -16px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hidden;

}
#timeTableInner ul  {
 width:320px;

}
#timeTableInner ul li {
float:left;
 width:80px;

}
```

```html
<div id="timeTableMask">
    <div id="timeTableInner">
        <ul id="timeText">
            <li class="t0000"><span class="hour">0:00</span></li>
            <li class="t0015">17:00</li>
             <li class="t2345">20:00</li>
            <li class="t2400"><span class="hour">24:00</span></li>
       </ul>
</div>
```